# Create a IP-Serial tunnel in Java

Tags: java, sockets, server, tunnel

First, i'm sorry for my english, i'm a french developer.

I work on a java client-server application with socket. The client software is on a pc, like the server, but the client pc is connected in USB to a device which listens to frames in a certain protocol, i shall name it protocol X. My server send frames to the client and the client send these frames with the protocol X.

Now, i want to use the protocol only on the server, and send the frames directly on the USB device. How can it be done? I heard about tunnel but i don't know java library which do that. 
I think that it's necessary to be able to encapsuler the X frame in a IP frame and send it to the client, which decapsulates and sent it to the usb device.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you already doing something similar as pure Java has only TCP/IP and UDP protocols implementing, so you are already wrapping your X prot.

Comment: `The client application is connected in USB to a device which listens to frames in a certain protocol, ` it is either badly written or simply irrelevant as there is no difference if you run your app from hdd, directly from network or a USB stick. And I assume you mean java client application

Comment: I badly gave explanation, my client software is on a pc and this pc is connected to an USB device. So, i have 3 machines, the server, the client and the device.

Comment: And i want to create a tunnel between the server pc and the USB device

Comment: Now that changes everything. Edit your post.

Comment: And what is the base of communications between client and the USB dev? Is it IP sockets?

Comment: Yes, java socket communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP encapsulation would work under three condition:

1. Your USB device would have to handle TCP connections (thus have network address know to the host PC)
2. host machine would have to have set routing table to route proper network trafic to your USB device.
3. USB dev should handle extraction of the propert data from incoming IP packets.

So using simple routing should be enough to handle that, based on information you have provided.

The other way around is to make proxy deamon relay - and this is exactly what you have now.

Comment: The USB device knows only the data formalized with the protocol X. I use a HDLC connection with it right now. In the protocol, i see TCP and HDLC-TCP connection  but I don't know at the moment if it's possible to use them.

Comment: @DamienRamat me neither.

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss, I understand better now